# Why does my alert statement not fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

When testing this code, I purposely make it so the text returned from the ajax call is not 1. It reaches that `else` statement. The other statements execute, however, I never see an alert.

```
  $.ajax ( {
    type: "GET",
    processData: false,
    url:  SITE_URL + "/system/check_user_project/" + session_id + "/" + cart_id + "/" + project_id + "/" + revision_id, //send data to this url
    dataType: 'text', 
  })
  .done (function(text) //When we have the data
  {
    if ("1" == text)
    {
      photos_populate_albums(session_id); //Call function to populate albums

      if (typeof(project_id) !== "undefined" && project_id > 0) //If we have a project
      {
        mattes_add_default_matte(null, null, null, null, SITE_URL + "/system/xml/export/" + project_id + "?rid=" + revision_id);
      }
      else //otherwise...
      {
        mattes_add_default_matte(); //Add the default matte
      }

      common_change_step(document.getElementById("step1")); //Set the step to 1
    }
    else
    {
      $("#content").empty();
      alert("Invalid project.");
      window.location.href = (SITE_URL + "/user/mystuff/projects/?pid=" + partner_id);
    }

  });
```

UPDATE: I just realized I accidentally checked the box that asks if you want to keep receiving alerts from this webpage when it came up. Now I don't know where to undo it.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No errors in the browser console

Comment: How do you know it reaches the else statement ?

Comment: Because it executes the other statements - it clears the content and it redirects to the other page

Comment: Tip: I would add the `.fail()` handler just to make sure it's executing the `AJAX` call properly.

Comment: Didn't you checked "do not show me alerts for this site" or anything like this ? If you are testing this on a server, did you make sure the code has been correctly uploaded ?

Comment: Yes, I just realized I accidentally checked that box when it came up. Now I don't know where to undo it.

Comment: Tip #2: The extra comma here can break your code on `IE`: `dataType: 'text',`

Comment: Not sure... close the tab, reopen it, empty your cache...

Comment: question: is the alert supposed pop up before or after the page redirection?

Answer (score 0):

The code works. To reset the alert setting I had to re-open the tab.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it's because you're doing a redirect just after the alert, and it is being supressed.

You may try replacing this:

```
$("#content").empty();
alert("Invalid project.");
window.location.href = (SITE_URL + "/user/mystuff/projects/?pid=" + partner_id);
```

For something like this:

```
$("#content").empty();
if (alert("Invalid project.") || true)
    window.location.href = (SITE_URL + "/user/mystuff/projects/?pid=" + partner_id);
```

Comment: The snippets in your answer are equivalent.